# How to select a blank(dummy) column in a JDatabse UNION query

Tags: mysql, jdatabase

I have two queries that I am combining using a UNION statement. I know that I need both queries to get the same number and type of arguments to work.

I have one query that only really needs three fields and one that needs four.

Eg query 1's select line looks like this

```
->select ($db->quoteName(array('c.event','b.date','b.type','a.mob')))
```

query 2's select line looks like this, XX denotes where I need to insert a dummy field:

```
->select ($db->quoteName(array('b.event','a.date','a.type', XX)))
```

What the syntax for putting a dummy field into the select statement of the second query please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it (short on time), but I think this should add a dummy column b.mob which is filled with string 'dummy'.

```
->select ($db->quoteName(array('b.event','a.date','a.type')))
->select ($db->quote('dummy'). ' AS ' . $db->quoteName('b.mob'))
```

The equivalent sql should be

```
SELECT `b.event`, `a.date`, `a.type`, 'dummy' AS `b.mob`
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried that but its throwing up an SQL error. Any other wise suggestions?

Comment: I've tested it now, and it works for me. Can you post the built query? Maybe there is another error somewhere. Like for example, I believe when you use UNION, the whole schema has to be the same, which includes the names. So b.event UNION a.event will give an SQL error.

Comment: Hi, I tried  `->select ($db->quote('dummy') .'AS'. $db->quote('mob'))` instead and it worked perfectly! Thanks! :0)

Comment: The error was likely generated by writing the table alias `b` into the dummy column name.  SQL was probably getting fouled up while trying to verify that the dummy column was a "real" column in the `b` table.  I didn't test, but I would recommend simply removing the table alias `b` (and delimiting `.`) and retaining user3154108's suggested `$db->qn()` since it is the appropriate call for backtick-wrapping a column name.